# How to replace time part of DATETIME input by value from TIME input

Tags: aura, datetime, javascript-controller, timezone, time

I've tried to find an algorithm (Salesforce, aura) but without success. Probably, you have any ideas!

I have:

- attribute

```
    <aura:attribute name="bulkApply" type="Map" default="{}"/>
```

- datetime input:

```
<lightning:input label=""
                 class="label-hidden"
                 variant="label-hidden"
                 type="datetime-local"
                 value="{!v.bulkApply.SchedStartTime}"
/>
```

- and time input:

```
<lightning:input type="time"
                 label=""
                 class="label-hidden"
                 variant="label-hidden"
                 name="startTimeOnly"
                 value="{!v.bulkApply.startTimeOnly}"
/>
```

This is what they look like and what I need to do:

[inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjmq8.png)

After click the button to action replace logic I have the following values:

```
 let startTimeOnly = cmp.get('v.bulkApply.startTimeOnly');
 let schedStartTime = cmp.get('v.bulkApply.SchedStartTime');

 console.log(startTimeOnly); //00:30:00.000
 console.log(schedStartTime);//2023-02-08T13:00:00.000Z

 //here should be algorithm
```

The main problem is that I have time value with applied user timezone and datatime value in UTC format. Salesforce User timezone is Australia (GMT+11). That is why I have 2023-02-08T13:00:00.000Z instead of 9 Feb, 00:00.
Please note, that **browser timezone** can be differ from **salesforce user** timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **split** of javascript.

```
Let dateAndTime = schedStartTime.split('T');
//This will return an Array
//dateAndTime[0] - date
//dateAndTime[1] - time
// You can replace the value at 1 index
```

You probably need to convert the dateTime into string.